# size mismatch while rotation ipad/iphone webview for youtube

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on YouTube Video playing  application where i need to play videos through `UIWebView` its working fine  when i m  rotating the devices from portrait to landscape mode.But When i click The Zoom option(Zoom Option means through `UIWebView`) and trying to rotate the Screen from portrait to landscape mode its showing white Blank screen in bottom right corner.and in case of landscape to portrait at bottom part its showing white blank screen.please help me out.

Comment: Please add some punctuation and improve the grammar to make your question clearer.

Comment: How you are initializing your WebView ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something do with your webviews background color. Anyway can you provide some screenshots to make it more clear.